# Unknown discovery type [gce]

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to configure [GCE Discovery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.1/discovery-gce-usage-long.html).

Have this in elasticsearch.yml

```
cloud:
  gce:
      project_id: ..........
      zone: us-west1-a
discovery:
      type: gce
```

Look at the log messages:

- `loaded plugin [discovery-gce]`
- but also failes with Unknown discovery type [gce]

.

```
[2018-01-16T09:11:25,247][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-2-node-2] loaded plugin [discovery-gce]
[2018-01-16T09:11:27,019][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] Exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown discovery type [gce]
        at org.elasticsearch.discovery.DiscoveryModule.<init>(DiscoveryModule.java:110) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:441) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:245) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:322) [elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:130) [elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:121) [elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:69) [elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134) [elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) [elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:85) [elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
```

What the heck is going on here? Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the EL maintaining team [did a BWC change](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/c652b586c46f8f3de6a5adf70c9be51ee945b620)

In 5.1 we introduced the  `discovery.zen.hosts_provider` setting to better reflect it. This PR removes BWC code in those plugins (GCE included) as it is not needed anymore.

```
- .put("discovery.type", "gce")
+ .put("discovery.zen.hosts_provider", "gce")
```

so the correct elasticsearch.yml configuration should reference

```
discovery:
      zen.hosts_provider: gce
```